# Wrangle facebook page for the all the friend name using Beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, html, facebook, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do the following: Wrangle my own Facebook page for all my friend names. I have initially stored my webpage as a local file and then parse it using BeautifulSoup. And I have used find_all method to look for all the elements of the following pattern: `<div class="name">friend name</div>`. However, when I run the code,I get an empty list containing no matches? So what do you is the problem

Thanks

Code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = "myFacebook.html" with open(page, "r") as html:
page_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print page_html.find_all(attrs = {"class" : "name"})
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup is not playing well with a downloaded Facebook page.  If you pull out all the `div` s you get an array of some `div`s but not the ones with the names in them, and the `get_text` method comes up without names also.

Comment: So which library do you think can do that job....

Comment: Facebook API?  https://developers.facebook.com  This is probably overkill for your problem, other than that I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the required information using python's regular expression
library -re.
Following is the simple script to pull friend names from facebook page stored locally as html file :

```
import re
page = "friends.html"

f = open(page,'r')
s = f.read()

regX = r'<div class="fsl fwb fcb">.*?</div>'## Making it less greedy using ?
for elem in re.findall(regX,s):
    print re.findall(r'<a.*>(.*)</a>',elem)[0]## getting the names text
```